# Find distribution function for $P(X\leq x)=1-1/(1-x)$ using $f(h^{-1}) \cdot |h'^{-1}|$

Tags: measure-theory

I my homework I have to show that for a random variable $X$ with distribution function $P(X\leq x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$ for $x>0$ and 0 everywhere else,

then the transform $h=a+bX, \, a,b\in \mathbb{R}, \, b>0$ is
$P(a+bX \leq x)=1-\frac{b}{b-a+x}$ for $x\geq a$

So I get $h^{-1}=\frac{y-a}{b}$ and $h'^{-1}=\frac{1}{b}$

In the solution they use that the density function is $f(x)=(\frac{1}{x+1})'=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ and the formula $f(h^{-1})\cdot|h'^{-1}|$.

However this gives me that $\frac{1}{(1+(\frac{y-a}{b}))^2}\cdot|\frac{1}{b}|$ which is nowhere near $1-\frac{b}{b-a+x}$

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have computed the  **density** of $h$ correctly but you are trying to compare it witht its **distribution function**. If you differentiate $1-\frac b {b-a+x}$ you will get exactly what you have arrived at for the density.

Comment: I mixed that together, thanks

Answer (score 3):

### They are asking for the *distribution* function, not for the *density* function

#### Case 1: $b$ is positive:

The book seems to be assuming this. If $P(X\le x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$, and $Y=h(X)=a+bX$ then the distribution function of $Y$ is

$$P(Y\le y)=P\left(X\le h^{-1}(Y)\right)=1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{y-a}{b}}=1-\frac{b}{b-a+y}$$

for $y\ge a$, and $0$ otherwise.

#### Case 2: $b$ is negative:

If $b<0$, a little more care is needed. Let $b=-c$, where $c$ is positive, and $Y=h(X)=a-cX$. Then,

$$P(Y\le y)=P\left(a-cX\le y\right)=P\left(X\ge\frac{a-y}{c}\right)=1-P\left(X\le \frac{a-y}{c}\right)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{a-y}{c}}=\frac{b}{b-a+y}$$

for $y\le a$, and $1$ otherwise. Here, I could replace $<$ with $\le$ because the distribution of $X$ is continuous, (i.e., there are no discrete points with positive probability mass).

### How to do this using the densities

Your book seems to ask you to do this using the density functions. This is really a detour and does not make much practical sense, but here it goes. I am going to only do the case $b>0$.

The density function of $X$ is

$$p_X(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2},\quad\quad\quad x\ge 0$$

and $0$ otherwise. If $Y=h(X)=a+bX$, then $X=h^{-1}(Y)=\frac{Y-a}{b}$, and $\left(h^{-1}\right)'(Y)=\frac{1}{b}$. Then, the density function of $Y$ is

$$p_Y(y)=p_X\left(h^{-1}(Y)\right)\left|\left(h^{-1}\right)'(Y)\right|=\frac{1}{b\left(1+\frac{y-a}{b}\right)^2}=\frac{b}{\left(b-a+y\right)^2}$$

for $y\ge a$, and $0$ otherwise. The distribution function of $Y$ is then

$$P(Y\ge y)=\int_{-\infty}^{y}p_Y(z)\;\mathrm{d}z=\int_{a}^{y}\frac{b}{\left(b-a+z\right)^2}\;\mathrm{d}z=1-\frac{b}{b-a+y}$$